How to convert XSD to JSON Schema using JavaScript in Postman script
How to convert XSD to JSON Schema using JavaScript in Postman scripts to validate JSON API requests and responses?
I used the below code to fetch the XSD in the Postman script but now trying to convert it into JSON schema.


pmFetch('https://Test/CreditSale.xsd')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseBody => {
    console.log('The response body:');
    console.log(responseBody);
    console.log('responseBody.title: "' + responseBody.title + '"');
  });
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
function pmFetch (url) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    pm.sendRequest(url, function (err, response) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}



Can someone please help me here?

Does this answer your question? Generate Json schema from XML schema (XSD)

No, i need this using postman
